# Not able submit form and add data in form_for in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-5, form-for

When I click the submit button in todo_list/show which renders form from todo_item suddenly the url in address box changes it coantains authenticity token and utf8  in it with params also visible in url only. So that's why might  be controller is not being triggered. Attaching code:

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'todo_items/create'
  resources :todo_lists do
    resources :todo_items
  end

  root "todo_lists#index"
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see 
  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Controller todo_item

```
class TodoItemsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :todo_list_params 

  def create
    @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:todo_list_id])

    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.create(params_item)
    redirect_to " todo_lists#index"  
  end

  private

  def todo_list_params
    @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:todo_list_id])
  end   

  def params_item
    params_item = params.require(:todo_item).permit(:content)  
  end  

end

end
```

FORM PARTIAL

```
<%= form_for([@todo_list , @todo_list.todo_items.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :content , placeholder: "write the content here"  %>
  <%= f.submit  %>
<% end %>
```

Adding logs: upper log is of successful creation of data in other controller and in is of this problem .You can easily see bottom log has weird URL and params how to repair it:
[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbBsf.png)

Comment: You can define `method: :post` along with the form_for parameter.

Comment: @Gokulp Default http_method type in form is `post` no need to add that.

Comment: Feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

1)=> routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "todo_lists#index"
  #get 'todo_items/create'
  resources :todo_lists, except: [:index] do
    resources :todo_items
  end
end
```

2)=> Run `rake routes`

```
todo_list_todo_items POST       /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items(.:format)     todo_items#create
```

3)_form.html.erb(replace url with `todo_lists#create` route by running rake routes.)

```
<%= form_for @todo_list.todo_items.new, url: todo_list_todo_items_path(todo_list_id: @todo_list.id) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :content , placeholder: "write the content here"  %>
  <%= f.submit  %>
<% end %>
```